# Cant submit my drupal form; it has an update query

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-modules

I am making a custom module which also enables an edit page to edit the special node .
Below the feilds there is an update button ; so i have made a form for all this and
following is my hook_submit for the form

```
      function game_week_edit_form_submit($form_id, &$form_state) 
       {
$result = db_query("UPDATE {game_week} SET 
  start_time = %s, open_time = %s , close_time = %s WHERE game_week_id= %d", 
        $form_state['values']['start_time'], $form_state['values']['open_time'],   
           $form_state['values']['close_time'],$form_state['values']['game_week_id']);  
   }
```

Comment: Is there an error message? What is happening (or not)?

Comment: It is not getting updated at the end of the function i am printing  $message = 'You have submitted the ' . $form_id . ' form which contains the following data:<pre>' . print_r($form_state,true) . '</pre>'; drupal_set_message(t($message));  and in the message i get all the updated values but not in the database

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to wrap your strings in the query with quotes:

```
function game_week_edit_form_submit($form_id, &$form_state) 
{
  $result = db_query("UPDATE {game_week} SET 
    start_time = '%s', open_time = '%s' , close_time = '%s' WHERE game_week_id = %d", 
    $form_state['values']['start_time'], $form_state['values']['open_time'],   
    $form_state['values']['close_time'],$form_state['values']['game_week_id']);
}
```

If that's not it, look in the **recent log entries** for any db fails - admin/reports/dblog

Comment: dude u r awesome its 2a.m. at my place and i almost gave it up. Thanks a lot man

Comment: np. its around midnight here :D